# Elastic search ignore the first words in the text

Tags: elasticsearch

Which filter/analyser should i use to ignore the first occurrence of the word such as "The", "A" etc in the text field

I tried using the Mapping Char filter to replace the words into empty string using

mappings" : ["The => ","A => "]

however it replaces all the words that has "the" in words such as their, there etc

Comment: Try [stopwords](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stop-tokenfilter.html) filter?

Comment: Since i am using a keyword analyzer, using stopwords does not solve the problem. i have to depend on Character filter that runs before the tokenizer